# How to stop Wi-Fi debug logging in /private/tmp?

Tags: wifi, macos, logs

I am not sure why this is happening, but on my macbook macOS Sierra log files are being written to `/private/tmp` that look like this:

```
wifi-11-25-2019__21:01:29.log   wifi-11-25-2019__21:06:18.log
wifi-11-25-2019__21:01:30.log   wifi-11-25-2019__21:06:19.log
wifi-11-25-2019__21:01:31.log   wifi-11-25-2019__21:06:20.log
wifi-11-25-2019__21:01:32.log   wifi-11-25-2019__21:06:21.log
wifi-11-25-2019__21:01:33.log   wifi-11-25-2019__21:06:22.log
wifi-11-25-2019__21:01:34.log   wifi-11-25-2019__21:06:23.log
wifi-11-25-2019__21:01:35.log   wifi-11-25-2019__21:06:24.log
wifi-11-25-2019__21:01:36.log
```

The only reason I found this was because System was over 100GB and I investigated with `Disk Inventory X` and saw the log files wasting my SSD. I have a feeling it is the airport utility.

How can I stop this from happening?

I option-clicked the Wi-Fi menu, unfortunately I only have "Create Diagnostics Report..." and "Open wireless diagnostics..." there.

Logs:

```bsh
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 SC: <airportd[57]> scInitInterface for device en0 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 Info: <airportd[57]> psCallback: powerSource = Battery Power 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 Info: <airportd[57]> psCallback: set powersave max throughput on en0 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 Roam: <airportd[57]> _initInterface: AirPort Interface <en0> <4> 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 P2P: <airportd[57]> _createP2PDeviceInterface: Attempting to create P2P device interface for en0 (attemptNumber = 0) 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 P2P: <airportd[57]> _createP2PDeviceInterface: Created P2P device interface p2p0 with address a:f9:d3:54:f9:91 for en0 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 P2P: <airportd[57]> CreateVirtualInterface: Attempting to create AWDL interface for en0 with MAC address 5e:97:e7:64:ff:ac (attemptNumber = 0) 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 P2P: <airportd[57]> CreateVirtualInterface: Created AWDL interface awdl0 with address 5e:97:e7:64:ff:ac for en0 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 SC: <airportd[57]> CoreCapture preference: 0 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 SC: <airportd[57]> finished with CoreCapture preferences 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 <airportd[57]> airportdProcessDLILEvent: en0 attached (up) 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 Driver Discovery: <airportd[57]> airportdProcessDLILEvent: en0 attached (up) 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 BTC: <airportd[57]> BluetoothCoexStatusMonitoringCallback: Bluetooth Status Notification 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 Driver Discovery: <airportd[57]> _interfaceAdded: p2p0 added. 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 Driver Discovery: <airportd[57]> _initInterface: p2p0 is down 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 SC: <airportd[57]> scInitInterface for device p2p0 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 Roam: <airportd[57]> _initInterface: AirPort Interface <p2p0> <5> 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 BTC: <airportd[57]> __BluetoothCoexHandleUpdateForNode: <en0> Handle Bluetooth Coex: FrequencyBand <0>, Bluetooth Bandwidth Utilization <0>, Clamshell Mode <0> 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 BTC: <airportd[57]> BluetoothCoexSetProfile: Old 2.4GHz BT Coex profiles: { 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "BTC_PROF_BAND" = 8; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "BTC_PROF_NUM" = 0; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 } 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 Roam: <airportd[57]> DISABLED, 2.4GHz on en0 => { 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "ROAM_PROF" = ( 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 { 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "ROAM_PROF_BACKOFF_MULTIPLIER" = 10; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "ROAM_PROF_FULLSCAN_PERIOD" = 3000; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "ROAM_PROF_INIT_SCAN_PERIOD" = 600; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "ROAM_PROF_MAX_SCAN_PERIOD" = 60000; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "ROAM_PROF_NFSCAN" = 1; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "ROAM_PROF_ROAM_DELTA" = 50; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "ROAM_PROF_ROAM_FLAGS" = 0; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "ROAM_PROF_ROAM_TRIGGER" = "-120"; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "ROAM_PROF_RSSI_BOOST_DELTA" = 0; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "ROAM_PROF_RSSI_BOOST_THRESH" = 0; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "ROAM_PROF_RSSI_LOWER" = "-128"; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 } 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 ); 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "ROAM_PROF_BAND" = 4; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 "ROAM_PROF_NUM" = 1; 
Tue Nov 26 14:37:28.858 } 

... 

Tue Nov 26 19:05:20.757 AutoJoin: <airportd[57]> Successful cache-assisted background scan request with channels {( 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:20.757 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf722c00> [channelNumber=161(5GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}, active], 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:20.757 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf7272c0> [channelNumber=165(5GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}, active], 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:20.757 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf724690> [channelNumber=52(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, DFS] 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:20.757 )} took 0.1287 seconds, returned 0 results 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:21.227 AutoJoin: <airportd[57]> Successful cache-assisted background scan request with channels {( 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:21.227 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf75cb60> [channelNumber=56(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, DFS], 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:21.227 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf72d900> [channelNumber=60(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, DFS], 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:21.227 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf716e70> [channelNumber=64(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, DFS] 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:21.227 )} took 0.4700 seconds, returned 0 results 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:21.228 Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[263]> scan cache updated 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:21.699 AutoJoin: <airportd[57]> Successful cache-assisted background scan request with channels {( 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:21.699 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf726450> [channelNumber=100(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, DFS], 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:21.699 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf7222d0> [channelNumber=104(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, DFS], 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:21.699 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf709420> [channelNumber=108(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, DFS] 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:21.699 )} took 0.4709 seconds, returned 0 results 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.172 AutoJoin: <airportd[57]> Successful cache-assisted background scan request with channels {( 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.173 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf731240> [channelNumber=112(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, DFS], 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.173 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf71a840> [channelNumber=116(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, DFS], 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.173 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf763e10> [channelNumber=120(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, DFS] 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.173 )} took 0.4737 seconds, returned 0 results 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.646 AutoJoin: <airportd[57]> Successful cache-assisted background scan request with channels {( 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.646 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf71aeb0> [channelNumber=124(5GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}, DFS], 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.646 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf7676f0> [channelNumber=128(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, DFS], 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.646 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf70ce10> [channelNumber=132(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, DFS] 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.646 )} took 0.4730 seconds, returned 0 results 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.646 Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[263]> scan cache updated 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.948 AutoJoin: <airportd[57]> Successful cache-assisted background scan request with channels {( 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.948 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf728ea0> [channelNumber=136(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, DFS], 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.948 <CWChannel: 0x7fabdf70b540> [channelNumber=140(5GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}, DFS] 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:22.948 )} took 0.3022 seconds, returned 0 results 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:23.623 Driver Event: <airportd[57]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: DUMP_LOGS (en0) 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:24.623 Driver Event: <airportd[57]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: DUMP_LOGS (en0) 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:25.623 Driver Event: <airportd[57]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: DUMP_LOGS (en0) 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:25.690 Info: <CoreWLAN PPPController[263]> canceling poll timer 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:26.634 Driver Event: <airportd[57]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: DUMP_LOGS (en0) 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:27.630 Driver Event: <airportd[57]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: DUMP_LOGS (en0) 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:28.625 Driver Event: <airportd[57]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: DUMP_LOGS (en0) 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:29.624 Driver Event: <airportd[57]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: DUMP_LOGS (en0) 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:30.623 Driver Event: <airportd[57]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: DUMP_LOGS (en0) 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:31.627 Driver Event: <airportd[57]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: DUMP_LOGS (en0) 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:32.627 Driver Event: <airportd[57]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: DUMP_LOGS (en0) 
Tue Nov 26 19:05:33.633 Driver Event: <airportd[57]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: DUMP_LOGS (en0)
```

Comment: I have the same in my machine at work but not in my machine at home. Both are running El Capitan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in the discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101502/discussion-between-stevie-g-and-ankii), OP fixed the issue by upgrading to High Sierra.

https://superuser.com/a/1253364 also documents a possible bug in Sierra, where the answerer downgraded to El Capitan.

---

- Hold <kbd>option</kbd> key and click on Wi-Fi icon in menu bar. Third or Fourth from the top would be enable/disable Wi-Fi logging.
- Open Airport Utility, Preferences and untick "Monitor AirPort base stations for problems".

  https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/aputility/aprt3fa98818/6.3.9/mac/10.15
- Open Wireless Diagnostics.app, go to Window Menu. I find Logs and Sniffer to be of interest. Click on Logs, Refresh for the sake of refresh and make sure that all of them are unticked.  Then restart.

[image]

In Sniffer, "Start" would require admin password. Start and then stop.

[image]

http://osxdaily.com/2015/04/23/sniff-packet-capture-packet-trace-mac-os-x-wireless-diagnostics/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately I only have `Create Diagnostics Report...` and  `Open wireless diagnostics...`

Comment: `10.12.6` MacOS Sierra

Comment: Managed to see this `Sniffing on channel 1: airport en1 sniff 1` when using `airport`

Comment: Open Airport Utility, Preferences and untick "Monitor AirPort base stations for problems"

Comment: It is unchecked. I am worried now - someone has turned on sniffing and I can't find any way to disable.

Comment: Either restart or kill the process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101502/discussion-between-stevie-g-and-ankii).