# How to Disable Airport Sniffing?

Tags: macos, wifi, airport, launchd

when I run the command `airport`, it tells me it is sniffing:

```
Sniffing on channel 1:
    airport en1 sniff 1
```

I have noticed that many log files are created in `/private/tmp`

There may be some bad actor that has done this to my mac.

How can I disable airport from sniffing?

I killed it using its PID, but it starts again.

Comment: I couldn't test running airport, as I'd have to do [this all](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130923/is-there-a-built-in-command-line-utility-for-airport-and-other-wifi-networks/130924#130924) on Mojave. But looks like you read from the *Examples* from the [help page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130923/is-there-a-built-in-command-line-utility-for-airport-and-other-wifi-networks/130924#130924)

Comment: @ankii You can run it by just pasting `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport` into Terminal

Answer (score 2):

If you run `airport` without arguments it just prints a description of its options and examples of how to use some of them, including `airport en1 sniff 1` to start sniffing. It does **not** report the current state of the interface.

To actually start sniffing you need to call the command as shown (and replace `en1` with your actual WiFi interface):

```
$ sudo airport en1 sniff
Capturing 802.11 frames on en1.
^CSession saved to /tmp/airportSniffHZ3nqn.cap.
$ ll /tmp/airportSniffHZ3nqn.cap 
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  24 Nov 26 10:10 /tmp/airportSniffHZ3nqn.cap
```

It will keep running (and capturing) until you press Ctrl-C. To analyze the captured data you can use `tcpdump` or Wireshark.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376041/how-to-stop-wi-fi-debug-logging-in-private-tmp. chatroom has all my suggestions negated.

Comment: @ankii Thanks. That seems unrelated to anything `airport` might do. `airport` logs (if enabled) are written to `/var/log/wifi.log`.

Comment: you can see the edit history.. I re-added airport tag after they added the sniff part. I added my defence (;p) in the comment above.

Comment: @ankii `airport` != Airport Utility. The first is used to manage the local WiFi interface, the second to manage an Airport device (WiFi router). I've removed the tag again nevertheless because assuming Airport Utility is involved goes beyond what the OP provided so far.

Comment: The contents of the log files at `/private/tmp/wifi-11-25-2019__21:01:30.log` contain lines saying `airportd`. Perhaps something else is doing this logging.

Comment: @StevieG Having a look at some of the full lines will help. `airportd` may log this on behalf of another application.